# How do I find repeating words in a string in c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a script in c# that finds repeating words in a string, and then store the words that were repeating.

Comment: Please provide some sample input and output data, and show the code you have so far so we can see where you're stuck.

Comment: This posts shows no effort and so, it is not useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking for a tutorial and not for help with a problem in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to split the string on the space character and define each item as a "word". Then you can use the `System.Linq` extension method `GroupBy` to group the words and get their `Count`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var words = "one two three one four three four nine five two three two";

    Console.WriteLine($"Given the input string:\n\"{words}\",\n");

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.Split(' ')
        .GroupBy(word => word)
        .Select(group => $"the word '{group.Key}' repeated {group.Count()} times")));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]